# proper syntax for perl unicode regular expression

Tags: perl, unicode

I am utterly confused as to why this perl one-liner:

```
echo à | perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 'if ($_ =~ /\x{1234}/g){print "it matches";};'
```

does not print "it matches"!
I am using perl version v5.18.1

Comment: Also, `if (/.../g)` makes no sense and can produce hard to debug errors. You want `if (/.../)`

Answer (score 0):

For enlightenment, try

```
echo à | perl -CSD -ne 'printf "%x",ord'
```